# why don't my images from ZBarCameraSimulator get processed?

Tags: zbar-sdk

In the simulator I'm using ZBarCameraSimulator to load a picture with a qrcode in it.

This never invokes the delegate method though

```
- (void) readerView:(ZBarReaderView*)view
     didReadSymbols:(ZBarSymbolSet*)syms
          fromImage:(UIImage*)image
```

ZBarReader works fine on an actual device though - is there something i'm overlooking about using ZBarCameraSimulator?

Comment: Have you found any solution of it.